# Which analysis method would be most suitable for multiple measures of exposure but only a single measure of outcome

Tags: time-series

I have physical examination data from 2010 to 2020 for a region, but not all individuals have data for the entire 11-year period. For example, some people only participated in 5 physical examinations between 2010 and 2020. Additionally, frailty diagnosis data is available for the year 2020. Therefore, I have a dataset with multiple measures of exposure but only a single measure of outcome. Which analysis method would be most suitable for this scenario?

One approach I am considering is trajectory or cluster analysis, for example exploring the relationship between changes in BMI from 2010 to 2020 and frailty in 2020.

Are there any other statistical analysis methods that would be more appropriate?